# How to config the gitolite repo path the way I don't need to bypass gitolite? Why gitlab app creates repos on the right path?

Tags: git, gitolite

I've installed Gitlab with gitolite, the fullsite works fine, its creating the repos just fine...

but then, when I try to push some code from a dev machine, it raises an error...

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitbox.com:10000/test_of_mine.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```

that outputs:

```
fatal: '/test_of_mine.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I bypass gitolite, adding a remote with full path, it finds the repo, but with another error, caused for bypassing

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitbox.com:10000/~git/repositories/test_of_mine.git
```

which returns

```
 Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
  Compressing objects: 100% (329/329), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (667/667), 785.81 KiB, done.
  Total 667 (delta 327), reused 639 (delta 311)
  remote: Empty compile time value given to use lib at hooks/update line 6
  remote: Use of uninitialized value in require at hooks/update line 7.
  remote: Can't locate Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at hooks/update line 7.
  remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line 7.
  remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
  To ssh://git@gitbox.com:10000/~git/repositories/test_of_mine.git
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@gitbox.com:10000/~git/repositories/test_of_mine.git'
```

Why I'm getting this errors? Am I missing any path config?

How to config the gitolite repo path, the way I don't need to bypass gitolite?

And why the gitlab app works fine, creating repositories on the right path, without raises any error?

Answer (score 1):

The [Issue 2950](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2950) mentions the same error, for a GitLab4.2 (note that GitLab 5.0 doesn't use gitolite anymore).

Try upgrading to the latest GitLab (using [`gitlab-shell`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell) instead of gitolite).

Or at least double-check the existence of a in `/home/git/repositories/`.

You shouldn't try to bypass gitolite in your current setup, but the second message is also seen in [Issue 1495](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1495):

> it happens because `$ENV{GL_LIBDIR}` isn't set and is required by [`~/.gitolite/hooks/common/update`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm#L162).

The installation of gitolite must have been incomplete. Plus make sure your gitolite is a V3.x, not a V2.

Comment: when I do bypass, it founds the repo, and raise an error specific caused by bypassing...

he repo is there, the gitlab app created it quite fine... the problem is with git clone and push :/ I mean with gitolite...

Comment: Nice to know it has changed...hope now Im thinking about reinstalling all the thing, anyway I appreciate your answer

If anyone know what config am I missing, plz help me :D

Comment: @MauroDias try and reinstall gitolite v3 (latest), and make sure `gitolite` is in your `PATH`: `GL_LIBDIR` is supposed to be `GL_BINDIR/lib`, and `GL_BINDIR` should refer to `/path/to/gitolite/install`, which should be declared in your `PATH`.